# What is the best place to store ADO.NET Data Services URLs in Silverlight apps?

Tags: c#, silverlight, wcf-data-services

I reference ADO.NET Data Service in my SilverLight project and I need to define URL for this Data Service. So the question is what is the best place to store this URL? When I used WCF Services it was generated ServiceReferences.ClientConfig, is there something similar for ADO Data Services?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's a data services on the local web app the URI should be relative and you shouldn't need it to be configurable.

If it's for a cross domain site but it doesn't change you could stick it in a xaml static resource.

If it needs to be user configurable it'll need to go into isolated storage on the client.